# How do i connect to LocalOnlyHotspot (Android 8.x+)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi

I've been successfully able to make a hotspot using [LocalOnlyHotspot](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/localonlyhotspot).
It gives me a hotspot with SSID Android_share_xxxx and unknown password.
How do I connect my other devices to this hotspot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the generated wifi configuration by:

```
        @Override
    public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
      super.onStarted(reservation);
      hotspotReservation = reservation;
      currentConfig = hotspotReservation.getWifiConfiguration();

      Log.v("DANG", "THE PASSWORD IS: "
          + currentConfig.preSharedKey 
          + " \n SSID is : "
          + currentConfig.SSID); 

      hotspotDetailsDialog();

    }
```